# .net garbage collection and high cpu

Tags: .net, ant, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

What are the conditions for the .net garbage collection not to run? does high cpu usage prevents the garbage collection from running?

I am working on a very large project with visual 2010 .net 4, 
I added new part of the project and now doing performance tests of it. 
during the tests I discover that when i put the clients in high load, almost 100% cpu all the time, the memory acts like there is a leak. after many tests which found nothing i used ANTS profiler, and found out than when I take snapshots each 5 minutes the memory acts like usual.
ANTS force the garbage collection to work, so I came out with the question, 
Does .net garbage collection does not work in high cpu for not interrupting the application run?

Comment: profile GC events with Perfview: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/PerfView-Tutorial-9-NET-Memory-Investigation-Basics-of-GC-Heap-Snapshots http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-10-Investigating-NET-Heap-Memory-Leaks-Part1-Collecting-the-data

Answer (score 2):

After checking the issue, I came to conclusion that the high CPU prevented the GC from working properly. 
I tested it with calling the GC each several minutes the memory stayed low as it should (in normal runs of the program). after it i forked the main bottle neck of the program to several cores. the cpu went down and the memory again act good as usual in c# and .net - went up and down in constant range.